# Won't let me use the class Stopwatch. in visual studio

Tags: c#, xna, stopwatch

I was trying to get farseer physics engine to work. Everything compiles fine except for one error that wont go away.

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Stopwatch' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It wont let me contruct a Stopwatch object. The error is point at this one line 
`private Stopwatch _watch = new Stopwatch();` 
Now i checked the references and I can find the stopwatch class in system.diagnostics, so I know its there, and I'm using System, I also put in System.diagnostics. Any help on what I can do to get it to find the Stopwatch class. I'm new to visual studio and xna, but I have prog exp w/ java.

EDIT: I added the reference Microsoft.Phone like v4vendetta said and it worked, Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show us your code? And do I understand you correctly: you have a `using System.Diagnostics;`-directive in your file where you use the `Stopwatch`?

Comment: Did you try adding `Microsoft.Phone` reference

Comment: Thanks man! I added this reference and it went away. Awesome!

Comment: @V4Vendetta: nice, didn't knew that. Since it apparently answers the questions you should make an answer of that.

Comment: @user566417 Great !! .. i added it as an answer, anyone with more details please free to add it to the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you would need a reference to `Microsoft.Phone`.

Never worked on them but got a hint from the following post which lead to my suggestion.

[Apparently this guy was unable to reference it](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/85269/513783.aspx).